# What is a point of relationships in view of index (search_api)?

Tags: views, search

What is a point of relationships in view that is showing an [search_api](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) index, if you can resolve relationships at search_api level - when you are choosing fields to index? Is there any?

Comment: I don't think anyone but authors and maintainers can answer this question the way it's written. How can we know their intentions? If it's in the docs you shouldn't need to ask, so I assume it isn't - and if so, we can guess just like you can. Also, your link is broken, let me fix it.

Comment: I disagree.  It is a setting on the UI that isn't terribly clear.